# Append div.html() to textarea.val() live function

Tags: jquery

I'm working on project where DOM structure is something like this :

```
<div id="wrapper">

     <p> Some Text Goes Here </p>   

     <ul id="sortable">
          <li>list 1</li>
          <li>list 2</li>
          <li>list 3</li>
          <li>list 4</li>
          <li>list 5</li>
     </ul>

</div>

<textarea id="cloner" rows="50" column="50"></textarea>
```

I'm appending #wrapper.html() to #cloner.val() using following simple function :

```
$('#cloner').val($('#wrapper').html());
```

Now, #wrapper contains lot of dragable/sortable/editable events. So, what I want is to reflect those changes inside textarea

Example : If I drag **list 5** to **list 2** position, this change within DOM should reflect inside  textarea live.

How can I achieve this [?](http://jsfiddle.net/2rW9h/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.sortable()` stop event, like so:

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
   stop: function() { $('#cloner').val($('#wrapper').html()); }
});
```

Comment: Ok! but there are other editable (Jedit) events as well.. So I need all in one solution..

Comment: you could always name the function and then assign it when building any and all events (draggable, etc) in the manner described above.

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach a stop event to the `draggable` method, in which you run:

```
$('#cloner').val($('#wrapper').html());
```

The same for sortable, editable, etc.

Or you can even copy that code into a function and just run that inside the `stop` event, so you would only have to update it in one place.